# Is there anything (feats/powers/items) that allows a sorcerer to teleport as a move action in Heroic Tier?

Tags: dnd-4e, teleportation

I am building a wild sorcerer "glass cannon" and I want to be able to teleport around the board.  Is it possible?

Comment: Strictly only a Sorcerer? There are classes like Swordmage and Warlock (Fey Pact) which specialise in teleporting around, but they're not Sorcerers.

Comment: It's unclear how exacting your limitations are for answers to this question. People are more likely to answer if they can feel confident their answers will actually be helpful; if you could provide more detail and context about your situation and requirements/restrictions, you'll probably get more answers.

Comment: Agreed, additional context is needed. Does it need to be at-will? How far does it need to go? Can we use multiclass feats?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about constant teleporting, but if you use the eladrin race you get the fey step encounter ability. This allows you take use a move action to telport the same distance you could move ignoring rough terrain and escaping monster without provoking opportunity attacks. This also could help you escape a hold that a monster may have on you.

This may not be what you are looking for, but could help during some encounters.

Answer (score 2):

The only really decent way to get at-will teleportation on a move action is to multi-class into warlock and use the Acolyte Power feat to swap your level 10 utility for the warlock utility Ethereal Sidestep.

Ethereal Sidestep is an at-will teleport 1 as a move action. Once you have it, you use feats and items to increase teleport distance.

Answer (score 0):

**'Guardian's Whistle'** (Wondrous Item, Level 4, Daily) lets you teleport a willing ally as a move action, so if someone else in your party had one they can rescue your sorceror.

Most item-activated teleports seem to be reactive, such as the Immediate Interrupt 2 square teleport of the **Bracers of Escape** (Arms Slot, Level 7), or the fall-rescue teleport of the **Feyleaf Sandals** (Feet Slot, Level 2)